# Android: WebView ActionBar (Honeycomb)?

Tags: android, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I have MyActivity with WebView element. When I "long press" on web view the ActionBar pops up. If I try to access the action bar like

```
getActionBar()
```

somewhere inside my activity I get null. It seems the web view is using some kind of menu popup.

QUESTIONS:

1. How can I access that action bar?
2. How to set the action bar not to move the activity down when it is displayed (so ActionBar to be on top of it > position:absolute)?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called an [`ActionMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html). You can make it overlay your Activity by setting `android:windowActionModeOverlay="true"` in your theme, like setting `android:windowActionBarOverlay` to have the `ActionBar` overlay content.

There is an ActionMode hook in Activity which you can maybe use: `onActionModeStarted()`.

Comment: I don't quite understand where to put this,  I dont't have a theme and adding it to the relative layout that forms my view doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You'll have to use a theme for this :)